# Android NDK Plugin trouble reading OpenGL header

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, android-ndk, adt

I am trying to use the new android NDK plugin that comes with ADT to write an OpenGL ES application. I am getting a getting undefined references for all my gl functions although I have added the correct path to the NDK under `Preferences -> Android -> NDK` and set the correct `Paths and Symbols` in the project properties. I am using Windows.

[image: Paths and Settings]

And yet I still get undefined references like so:

[image: code]

[image: errors]

I am using `CDT 8.0.2` because apparently the newer version broke the way the NDK plugin looks for paths. I am using `ADT 20.0.3`. My eclipse version is `Juno 4.2.0`. Does anyone know why it cant find the headers that are clearly there?

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := libgweng
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := game.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to do this with the NDK, just write an appropriate makefile for an Android build.

Look at the source code in the `hello-gl2` example that comes with the NDK; give attention to the `Android.mk` of this example.

Comment: I can already build the project with ndk-build and an appropriate makefile, what about the ndk plugin?

Comment: @TomFobear i can build an NDK based project without a problem with the latest Eclipse CDT and NDK plugin, you probably have a wrong configuration; did you have enabled the C/C++ support for your project? It's a thing that you have to do manually for an Android project under Eclipse.

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot to mention I did that by right clicking the project there was an option to "Add c++ behavior". I will update the question with my makefile. Also, I can build the project fine when I comment out all the GL code.

Comment: @TomFobear again, just look at the Android.mk in that example. You have a linking problem that can be solved if you just re-use what is inside that makefile.

Comment: Yea that was it :-x TY. By any chance can you help me understand 
`LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -lGLESv2`?

Comment: @TomFobear the flag `-l` indicates the name of a libraries to the toolchain, the compiler knows that it has to take this library into account for the linking phase. the variable `LOCAL_LDLIBS` is just the assigned container for all this flags to keep things organized so the NDK also knows in what variables it has to look for what. if you want to know more about all the libraries available by default just look at `<NDK root>/docs/STABLE-APIS.html`